# MYSQL Find the nearest time from table

Tags: mysql

I have a table which is consist of time as follow

**tblTime**

```
id  | in_time
-------------  
1   | 08:00
2   | 16:00
```

Now i am have a time value `08:45` and `16:10`, and i want to get the ID from **tblTime** for the nearest time to my time value, so the result will be `1` for `08:45` and `2` for `16:10` in this case.

I tried ABS() function but it seem it is not working at all.

```
SELECT * FROM tblTime ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMP(minute,in_time,'08:45'))
SELECT * FROM tblTime ORDER BY ABS(TIMESTAMP(minute,in_time,'16:10'))
```

Comment: Define `nearest`. Also give couple of more expected rows

Comment: care to give some example?

Comment: I meant if you can give some more sample data and your expected output. Because you said `nearest`, which is not clearly defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use function [`TIMEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff):

```
order by abs(time_to_sec(timediff(in_time, '08:45')))
limit 1 -- Of course, if you want nearest one, this line is necessary.
```

Note:
    `time_to_sec` will convet time to secs.